# Unorder multiple factor variables at once with data.table R

Tags: r, data.table

How do I unordered multiple factors at once in R?

I just want to share my solution with a `data.table` object.

Toy dataset:

```
dt<-data.table(
  variable1 = 1:5,
  variable2 = c(1,2,5,6,8),
  variable3 = factor(c("a","b","c","d","e"), ordered=T),
  variable4 = factor(c("ka","ba","ca","da","er"), ordered=F)
  )
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many variables you have you can also do this
first find the column(s) that are ordered and then only apply over those columns.

```
cols <- which(sapply(dt, is.ordered))
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, factor, ordered = F), .SDcols = cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

One (fast) option is simply modifying the class attribute:

```
for (i in seq_len(ncol(dt))) {
  if (is.ordered(dt[[i]])) setattr(dt[[i]], "class", "factor")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (not the prettiest I admit):

```
dt <- dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x)if(is.ordered(x)==T){factor(x,ordered = F)}else{x})]
```

I am happy to see cleaner solutions, even using tidyverse or base R!